# Dynamically adding column names in R Shiny

Tags: r

Quite New to R here and not an experienced coder. I want to create a simple function to upload an external file via R shiny, but the file will not have fixed number of columns and may or may not have a column name.

In the case where the raw file does not have a header, I wish to force the name of the first column to be "Date" and the remaining columns 2,3,4...,n to be "Investment 1","Investment 2","Investment 3",...,"Investment n-1" respectively

Here's my current code, server side,

```
server <- function(input, output) {

rawdata <- reactive({
file_to_read = input$file
if(is.null(file_to_read)) {
  return()
} 
    data <- read.table(file_to_read$datapath, sep = input$sep, header = 
input$dataheader)
})


addcolumn <- reactive({
if(input$dataheader = FALSE) {
paste("Date",colnames(rawdata()[,1]))
  for (i in 2:ncol(rawdata())) {
    paste("Investment " + i, colnames(rawdata()[,i]))
  }
}
})

output$datatable <- renderTable({
If(input$dataheader = FALSE) {
  addcolumn(rawdata())
} else {
rawdata()
}
})
```

and ui side,

```
dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "import",
        fluidRow(
          box(
            title = "Instructions",
            solidHeader = TRUE,
            width = 12,
            status = "warning",
            height = 120, 
            textOutput("instructionsImport")
          ),
          box(
            solidHeader = FALSE,
            width = 3,
            status = "primary",
            fileInput("file","Choose a file to upload"),
            radioButtons("sep","Separator",choices = c(Comma = ",", Space = " ",Period = ".", Tilde = "~", minus = "-")),
            checkboxInput("dataheader","File has header?")
          ),
          box(
            title = "Uploaded Data",
            solidHeader = TRUE,
            width = 9,
            status = "primary",
            tableOutput("datatable")
          )
        )
      ),
```

Ideally, I would like the operation of adding column name to be done once after import and the resulting data table created instead of making a reactive function for adding column.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Your question is legit, but I would suggest to focus on reading and renaming part, `shiny` has nothing to do with that. You might want to restructure your question, remove shiny part, rename and add examples data (file w/wo header)

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for the tips! It's my first time asking on SO, but I'll be more clear and succinct next time!

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `server.R` code to that :

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  rawdata <- reactive({
    file_to_read = input$file
    if(is.null(file_to_read)) {
      return()
    } 
    data <- read.table(file_to_read$datapath, sep = input$sep, header = 
                         input$dataheader)
    if(!input$dataheader){
      colnames(data)<-c("Date",paste("Investment",1:(ncol(data)-1)))
    }
    return(data)
  })


  output$datatable <- renderTable({
    rawdata()
  })
}
```